# Complex GSheets Query equation shows N/A even when I know the range has relevant data in it

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have a complex gsheets query formula that previously worked - suddenly stop working a few months ago.

It's purpose is to search timesheet data ( Respostas do Formulário 1'!$C$2:$H )
to match an employee number ( B50 )
based on a column of employee numers ( C )
and matching a string ( 'Domingos / Sundays' ) from a variety of options in column ( F ) which then returns the date in column ( G )

```
=IF(ISNA(CONCATENATE((transpose(query(transpose(UNIQUE(query('Respostas do Formulário 1'!$C$2:$H; "select G where C contains '"&$B50&"' AND F contains 'Domingos / Sundays' order by G format G 'DD/MM, '")));;COLUMNS(UNIQUE(query('Respostas do Formulário 1'!$C$2:$H; "select G where C contains '"&$B50&"' AND F contains 'Domingos / Sundays' order by G format G 'DD/MM, '"))))))));"";CONCATENATE((transpose(query(transpose(UNIQUE(query('Respostas do Formulário 1'!$C$2:$H; "select G where C contains '"&$B50&"' AND F contains 'Domingos / Sundays' order by G format G 'DD/MM, '")));;COLUMNS(UNIQUE(query('Respostas do Formulário 1'!$C$2:$H; "select G where C contains '"&$B50&"' AND F contains 'Domingos / Sundays' order by G format G 'DD/MM, '"))))))))
```

What it should do:

- if the result of the search is "N/A" return blank
- if not, display the result of the search
- concatenate the search results (to display in one cell)
- collate unique values so no repetition
- transpose the results (to display horizontally rather than vertically)
- Select G where C is equal to cell B and column F matches a string
- Order by date (G) and in the format DD/MM

What it is doing:

Returning blank (N/A) even when there is matching data in the search.

It's complex, but it worked and I can't see why it stopped working.

What I've tried:

- rewriting the formula from first principles, outcome is the same
- checking the revision history going back to the last time it worked - formulas are identical but results are different
- changing the format of the reference cell and data from number/text to see if it makes a difference
- Reducing the search down to it's simplest part, e.g just the query:

```
query('Respostas do Formulário 1'!$C$2:$H; "select G where C contains '"&$B50&"' AND F contains 'Domingos / Sundays' order by G format G 'DD/MM, '")
```

to see if it returns N/A or not - there's no change.

The only thing I can think of is that the syntax or way sheets handles any of these methods may have changed in the time since the sheet in question was made (Late 2020)

Last confirmed working in December 2020.

Any comments, questions or suggestions appreciated.

[Test Sheet:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ei5EEyri4w71JbF0ehssNaWcvjigVM_CoALPGo6nN-o/edit?usp=sharing) Hilariously, the test sheet works - but the real sheet doesn't! That just raises more questions!

I'll keep searching - at least I know that the formula works

Thanks.

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 2):

I worked out what had happened, the sheet was in portugal locale but originally was in UK, there is a difference of symbols from , to ; between the two.

Also, rogue copy/pasting had mis-matched some of the data in the original.

Although the formulas were perfect - the problem and solution were simple.